# What is the easiest way to return multiple components in one RenderFragment?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

A `RenderFragment` expects only one component to be returned, but that one component may have nested components:

```cs
private RenderFragment CreateRenderFragment()
{
    // This works
    return
    @<div>
        <text>Hello</text>
        <text>world!</text>
    </div>;

    // and so does this
    // return @<span><text>Hello</text> <text>world!</text></span>;
}
```

If we don't want to enclose the components in a `<div>` or `<span>` we can create a razor component following the `ChildContent` convention, e.g. `ChildContentComponent`:

```cs
@ChildContent

@code
{
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

and then use this component as a wrapper:

```cs
private RenderFragment CreateRenderFragment()
{
    return
    @<ChildContentComponent>
        <text>Hello</text>
        <text>world!</text>
    </ChildContentComponent>;
}
```

I may be mising something, but I can't see any other way to create a `RenderFragment` with multiple components. Neither of the following compile:

```cs
private RenderFragment CreateRenderFragment1()
{
    return @<text>Hello</text> <text>world!</text>;
}

private RenderFragment CreateRenderFragment2()
{
    return
    @:@{
        <text>Hello</text>
        <text>world!</text>
    } // ; expected, but will not compile with, either
}
```

Is there an easier way than the `ChildContentComponent` approach, or is there already a standard component which simply declares a `public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }`?

**EDIT:**
Based on MrC aka Shaun Curtis's answer below, the solution is `__builder => { ... };`

```cs
private RenderFragment CreateRenderFragment3()
{
    return __builder =>
    {
        <Widget1>Hello</Widget1>
        <Widget2>world!</Widget2>
    };
}
```

**Edit 2:**
And as Dimitris Maragkos and H H pont out below, `<text>` is a special do-nothing wrapper which is equivalent:

```cs
private RenderFragment CreateRenderFragment3()
{
    <text>
        <Widget1>Hello</Widget1>
        <Widget2>world!</Widget2>
    </text>
}
```

Comment: `return @<text><span>Hello</span><span>world!</span></text>;` works.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos My examples were deliberately trivial. What I really want is multiple components not wrapped in a div or span. The __builder => { ... }; syntax solves it.

Comment: I didn't wrap them in div or span but in `<text>`. `<text>` is a special tag for razor. Check H H's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75820563/10839134) which suggests the same. You could do `return @<text><Widget1>Hello</Widget1><Widget2>world!</Widget2></text>;`. `<text>` will not render, only the child components.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos and @H H thanks, I've learned something new as well. I've been using Ant Blazor which has a <Text> which isn't quite the same as <text>. In my example I just used <text> as a trivial component, not realising it was almost the answer to my own question.

Comment: For anyone else going down this rabbit hole, you can learn more about <text> here:
https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax

Comment: Interesting article, quite old. The feature is pre-Blazor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `RenderFragment` is a delegate defined like this:

```cs
public delegate void RenderFragment(RenderTreeBuilder builder);

public delegate RenderFragment RenderFragment<TValue>(TValue value);
```

This is my `ChildContentComponent` so it stands out on the page:

```cs
<div class="bg-light m-2 p-2 border">
    @ChildContent
</div>

@code
{
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

I think this block of code may help you.  Apologies if it confuses.   Any questions, ask.  Components, the Renderer and RenderFragments take a while to understand.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@MyForm

@code {
    // These two blocks use mixed C# and Razor markup
    // it works because this is a Razor file so will be compiled by the Razor Compiler
    // __builder is the RenderTreeBuilder provided by BuildRenderTree in a Razor component file
    private RenderFragment MyForm => (__builder) =>
    {
        <ChildContentComponent ChildContent=this.ABitOfContent />

        <ChildContentComponent>Another Hello</ChildContentComponent>

        <ChildContentComponent>And Another!!</ChildContentComponent>

        <ChildContentComponent>
            @this.ABitOfContent
            @this.ABitOfContent
            @this.ABitOfContent
            @this.AnotherBitOfContent
            <ChildContentComponent>
                @this.AnotherBitOfContent
            </ChildContentComponent>
        </ChildContentComponent>

        @this.AnotherBitOfContent
    };

    private RenderFragment ABitOfContent = (__builder) =>
    {
        <div>Hello Blazor</div>
    };


    // This block is an example of what the Razor Compiler compiles a markup block into in the C# file
    private RenderFragment AnotherBitOfContent => (builder) =>
    {
        builder.OpenComponent<ChildContentComponent>(0);
        builder.AddAttribute(1, "ChildContent", this.ABitOfContent);
        builder.CloseComponent();
    };
}
```

You can view the C# classes that the Razor compiler emits from Razor files by adding `EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles` to the project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
      <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Files are emitted to:

*./obj/Debug/netX.0/generated*

Comment: Thanks, __builder => { ... }; is the solution. I showed two versions of CreateRenderFragment() merely as examples. I updated my question to avoid confusion. Feel free to update your answer to remove the talk about the same signature, as that wasn't the point of the question.

Comment: Done.  I added how to get the compiler to output the compiler C# files.  Viewing them can often be very instructive and useful in finding out how the DotNetCore Blazor team code something.

Answer (score 5):

There is a trick that bUnit calls the [Secret Sauce](https://bunit.dev/docs/getting-started/writing-tests.html?tabs=xunit#secret-sauce-of-razor-files-tests)

```
private RenderFragment CreateRenderFragment =>
    @<text>
        <div>Hello</div>
        <Widget>world!</Widget>
    </text>;
```

Only the `<div>` and the `<Widget>` are rendered, not he `<text>`.

This apparently is a special rule for the outer `<text>` in a RenderFragment.