razor text element in svg
I am having trouble putting binding svg text elements in razor.  If I do this
<svg>
    <text x="1">hello world</text>
</svg>

it works fine - but if I do this:
<svg>
    @for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    <text x="1">hello world</text>
    }
</svg>

it gives me an error saying text elements can't contain attributes - ie clearly it's forgotten that it's inside svg.
I can sort of hack around it by going
<svg>
    @for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    <text><text x="1">hello world</text></text>
    }
</svg>

which works but is ugly as - anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it?

Because in this context <text> is not html / xml, it's razor syntax to swap back from c# to html output. You could use @: instead?

I had a test with .Net 8 and this @: looks good to work. https://i.sstatic.net/7oJLwR7e.png

This might allow Razor to treat the text as raw HTML but not interpret it as Razor markup

I think this method is bugged too, if you try to use variables, as in: @:<text x="1" y="@(15*i)">hello world</text> which didn't output right for me.

Just like what you test, since we used @for within , then the content should use razor syntax, and in razor syntax, <text> is used for render HTML that isn't surrounded by an HTML tag. However in our scenario, we just want <text> to be recognized as raw HTML. This is a conflict bewteen the syntax. <text><text x="1">hello world</text></text> shall be a "good" workaround although it looks ugly.

related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75819532/60761

I'd report this as a bug.  I found a couple ways to do this:
<svg>       
    @for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        @((MarkupString)$"""<text x="1" y="{i*20}">hello world</text>""")
    }
</svg>
<svg>       
    @for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        <g><text x="1" y="@(i*20)">hello world</text></g>
    }
</svg>

I think just putting each text in a new group is unlikely to harm anything in your <svg> markup.  But it seems to be an oversight that VS / Blazor doesn't correctly identify the markup context as svg with just <text>.

It's not a bug, just old (pre Blazor) razor syntax. See the link posted by @TinyWang.

I'd disagree that it's not a bug.  <svg> tags are supported, but here is a use case where the framework does not correctly identify the context.  The framework should know this, as the <text> is a child of the <svg> tag.  Maybe there should be a namespace for SVG so you could do <svg.Text>
